# Call a schema with arrays as parameters

Tags: c++

I have a class: `Schema` and would like to pass two parameters to it: `keys` and `types`. Coming from an Object oriented and non-statically typed language, Node.js/Python, C++ is quite confusing. I wrote this code which is meant to create a schema from two arrays, but for now will be limited to setting public variables and printing those from the main function. Here's the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Schema {
    public:
    string keys;
    Schema (string keys1[], string types[]) {
        keys = keys1;
    };
};

int main() {
    string keys[2] = {"name", "email"};
    string types[2] = {"string", "string"};
    Schema names(keys, types);
    cout << names << endl;
}
```

For some reason, I get these errors:

```
main.cpp:17:12: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Schema'
    Schema names(keys, types);
           ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:9:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'std::__cxx11::string [2]'
      to 'std::__cxx11::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>') for 1st argument
    Schema (string keys1, string types[]) {
    ^
main.cpp:6:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument,
      but 2 were provided
class Schema {
      ^
main.cpp:6:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument,
      but 2 were provided
1 error generated.
exit status 1
```

Why does this happen? I read a bunch of articles on how to use classes and functions and arrays, so I am not sure what is wrong.

## Edit:

Thanks to the helpful comments of Ted, jkb, and heap underrun, I attempted to fix it. However, this still doesn't seem to work. What went wrong?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Schema {
    public:
    string keys[];
    string types[];
    Schema (string keys1[], string types1[]) {
        keys = keys1;
        types = types1;
    };
};

int main() {
    string keys[2] = {"name", "email"};
    string types[2] = {"string", "string"};
    Schema names(keys, types);
    cout << names.keys << endl;
}
```

Errors:

```
error: flexible array member 'keys' of type
      'std::__cxx11::string []' with non-trivial destruction
        string keys[];
               ^
1 error generated.
exit status 1
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to build an object on the fly by defining its member fields at runtime. That's not going to be easy. If your `Schema` needs a name and an email address, just add those as member variables: `string name; string email;` and adjust the constructor accordingly.

Comment: Try fixing the assignment of an array of strings to a single string in the constructor: `keys = keys1`. You are also trying to insert your `Scheme` object into the `cout` stream without an appropriate `<<` operator.

Comment: In the class, you declare `public: string keys;`. That's a public member variable of type `std::string`, i.e., a **single** string, not an array of strings. In constructor, you have `string keys1[]` parameter, which is an **array** of strings. Then, in constructor, you do `keys = keys1`, as if trying to assign that array to the member variable. Why? You can't assign an array of strings to a single string. Also, `cout << names` won't work, because `names` is an instance of your custom class (`Schema`) and thus does not have the `operator <<` overload necessary to print it to `count`.

Comment: @heapunderrun thanks for the detailed comment! I edited my question, what went wrong?

Comment: Several issues… Firstly, array declarations in the form `sometype somename[]` (i.e., where the number of elements is omitted, thus using just empty brackets) are called _arrays of unknown bound_. Such arrays are incomplete types, they cannot be class members in C++. (C does allow such an array to be the last member of a `struct`, as a special case, and calls it a _flexible array member_, but not C++.) Secondly, you cannot assign/copy raw arrays just like `keys = keys1` (you need `std::memcpy` or `std::copy` for that). Thirdly, raw arrays are an somewhat obsolete legacy from C,…

Comment: … in C++ those stack-based raw arrays are mostly superceded with dynamic (heap-based) arrays called vectors. Vectors can grow, arrays cannot. Vectors are convenient to use; raw arrays are a nuisance, especially for beginners. So, instead of (ab)using C-style arrays, prefer to `#include <vector>` and use the [**`std::vector`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) class. (Or, in case your array has a very small, **fixed** size, and you really prefer to have it stack-based for some reason then at least use the `std::array` and `#include <array>`.) See also Anton Tchekov's answer.

Comment: By the way, if you intend to store key-value pairs (like keys strings and corresponding types strings), there is a better container for that, see [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). So, instead of two separate arrays or vectors, you could have `std::map<std::string, std::string> keys_and_types;` (don't forget to `#include <map>` for that).

Comment: Anyway, I'm not sure I understand the purpose of your `Schema` class at all. Like Ted Lyngmo has explained in his comment to Anton Tchekov's answer, in C++ you cannot create a class definition on-the-fly (from parameters or so). C++ is a statically-typed language, so all classes (such as your `Schema` class) need to be defined at compile time, they cannot change (i.e., altering list of or type of their members) at runtime. (There are templates, though, but those are still just another kind of static typing.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with C++ vectors instead of arrays because as containers they can be copied.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Schema {
    public:
    vector<string> keys;
    Schema (vector<string> keys1, vector<string> types) {
        keys = keys1;
    };
};

int main() {
    vector<string> keys = {"name", "email"};
    vector<string> types = {"string", "string"};
    Schema names(keys, types);
    cout << names.keys[0] << endl;
    cout << names.keys[1] << endl;
    //cout << names << endl;
}
```

To print the `names` object you would need to write a ostream operator function.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, object&);
```

Comment: This is leading OP down a dark alley of problems. If I'm reading OP:s python inspired attempt correctly, the hope is to make `keys` into actual members of the class with the types defined in `types` - which is not going to work.